# Finding the Flow of a Vector Field on a Plane

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following autonomous vector field on the plane:

\begin{align}
\dot{x}=-\omega y\\
\dot{y}=wx
\end{align}

where $(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^{2}$ and $\omega>0$. Show that the flow generated by this vector field is given by

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    x(t) \\
    y(t) \\
    \end{pmatrix}
=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \text{cos}\hspace{1mm}\omega t & -\text{sin}\hspace{1mm}\omega t \\
    \text{sin}\hspace{1mm}\omega t & \text{cos}\hspace{1mm}\omega t \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    x_0 \\
    y_0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}.
$$

I have attempted to solve the above ODEs by implicit integration and obtained $x(t)=\dfrac{x_{0}}{1-\omega^{2}yt}$ and $y(t)=-\dfrac{x_{0}\omega^{2}yt}{1-\omega^{2}yt}+y_0$, and am not sure how to proceed from here - appreciate any pointers I can get, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
\begin{align}
\dot x &= -\omega y \\ \dot y &= \omega x
\end{align}
If $x$ and $y$ are differentiable, then the equations above show they are twice differentiable. By differentiating again one has
\begin{align}
\ddot x &= - \omega^2 x \\ \ddot y &= - \omega^2 y
\end{align}
Thus, $x(t) = x_0\cos\omega t + \frac{x'(0)}{\omega}\sin\omega t$ and $y(t) = y_0\cos \omega t + \frac{y'(0)}{\omega}\sin\omega t$. The coupling of $x$ and $y$ show in fact that $x'(0) = -\omega y_0$ and $y'(0) = \omega x_0$, and thus
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}x(t) \\y(t)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\cos\omega t & -\sin\omega t \\\sin\omega t  & \cos \omega t \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_0 \\ y_0\end{pmatrix} 
\end{align}

A more technical but direct way is to solve the differential equation for vectors:
\begin{align}
X' = MX
\end{align}
where $M = \begin{pmatrix}0 & -\omega \\ \omega & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. This is a constant coefficient differential equation so $X(t) = \exp(Mt)X(0)$. Just compute $\exp(Mt) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(Mt)^n}{n!}$: one can easily show it is $\begin{pmatrix}\cos\omega t & -\sin\omega t \\\sin\omega t  & \cos \omega t \end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Why implicit integration ?
Differentiate first DE $x''=-wy'=-w^2x \implies x''+w^2x=0$ and solve. $\implies x(t)=c_1\cos (wt)+c_2\sin (wt)$.

Do the same for the second differential equation.